# PiCamera2 images with boxes and labels overlay with vis_util

Tags: camera, opencv, picamera

I'm trying to get integrate tensorflow and picamera2 to do some basic object detection.

The logic works out fine (I think), but I'm struggling to draw the boxes/labels deduced on top of the image.

```
camera = Picamera2()
camera.start()
while True:
      frame = camera.capture_array()
      #Changing the dimensions of the frame to feed to model
      frame1 = np.copy(frame)
      frame1.setflags(write =1)
      frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
      frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame_rgb, axis = 0)
      #feeding frame into model "sess"
      (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
             [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections], feed_dict = {image_tensor:frame_expanded})
      

      #Here's the issues: 
      visualization_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            frame, np.squeeze(boxes), np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32), np.squeeze(scores), category_index, use_normalized_coordinates = True, line_thickness = 8)

      #Other stuff
```

This is a truncated version of my code.

Running this we run into errors at vizualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/[user]/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/Object_detection_picamera.py", line 176, in

```
vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
```

File "/home/[user]/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py", line 1251, in

visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array
draw_bounding_box_on_image_array(
File "/home/[user]/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py", line 163, in draw_bounding_box_on_image_array
np.copyto(image, np.array(image_pil))

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (768,1024,3) into shape (768,1024,4)

I actually can't find a solid example of picamera2 + opencv + tensorflow (everything I can see is picamera which seems to use different methods).

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution might be to use frame[:,:,:3] for the visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array function in your example code, which worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/133029)